# How to increase the length/size of HTML5 input type of range

Tags: html

How can I increase the length/size of the HTML5 [range input](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_range)
 to make it longer/bigger?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/" method="get">
  Points:
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tired attribute `size="100px"` and also `width="100px"` but they didn't work. I wonder if it is even possible to change the lenght/size of HTML5 range input:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modifying the width works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/592ydrk2/. Note you need to use CSS, not old, deprecated attributes.

```css
input[type="range"] {
  width:400px;
}
```

```html
<form action="/" method="get">
  Points:
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the width via CSS

```
<input type="range" style="width: 500px;" value=10>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `size` attribute won't work on an `input` element with type `range`.  However, you can use CSS to easily make it bigger or smaller:

```css
input[type=range] {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/" method="get">
  Points:
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The width property works fine

```css
input[type="range"]{
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/" method="get">
  Points:
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
input[type="range"]{
width:500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can`t change the length/size of the HTML5 range input without using CSS.

the only attributes you can use are value, min, max and step. And none of those do what you need.

Find Styling the Slider on [This](http://thenewcode.com/757/Playing-With-The-HTML5-range-Slider-Input) for more information